# External libraries in C# project on github

Tags: c#, licensing, github, unity-container, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to push my project to github and I have two references in the project. Mainly Rhino Mocks and Unity. Is it ok from a legal point of view to put those dll's in a library folder within the solution so as nobody would have to download them manualy ?

My point is I would like the project to be more portable and less dependent on the location of those references on my machine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is yes to [Rhino Mocks](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-mocks), (but also distribute [license.txt](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-mocks/blob/master/license.txt)) and yes to Unity since it is under the [Ms-PL](http://unity.codeplex.com/license). If you are not changing any of the code, or trying to pass those DLLs off as your own work, you are fine.

Comment: So I just need to add DLL for Rhino with it's license, and a Unity DLL with Ms-PL license to my solution if I'm correct ?

Comment: yes just DLLs and license files would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The only way of finding out is by reading the license for your two libraries. Some software don't allow for secondary distribution even if they allow anyone to download software from their sites. The keyword here is redistribution. Either they allow it or they don't. Note that if the libraries are licensed under the GPL or the LGPL, and you want to distribute libraries as DLL, then you you must fulfill the GPL and LGPL requirements of offering the source code.